# How to extend Customer entity of Broadleaf Commerce?

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I was trying to extend the Customer entity in my application based on DemoSite 5.0.1-GA. I had extended the original Customer interface and CustomerImpl class. Then added my CustomerImpl class into persistence-core.xml and applicationContext-entity.xml in the core project, overriding the bean with id "org.broadleafcommerce.profile.core.domain.Customer".

I could extend the Order entity successfully by these steps. But for the Customer entity, I found that I would always get an instance of org.broadleafcommerce.profile.core.domain.CustomerImpl, whether in relative entities like Order or directly get the "org.broadleafcommerce.profile.core.domain.Customer" bean from Spring context, but not an instance of my extended class as expected.

Here is my applicationContext-entity.xml, I omitted the attributes of the `<beans>` element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans>
    <bean id="org.broadleafcommerce.core.order.domain.Order" class="com.ddklife.core.ecommerce.domain.OrderImpl" scope="prototype"/>
    <bean id="com.ddklife.core.autovending.domain.MachineChannel" class="com.ddklife.core.autovending.domain.MachineChannelImpl" scope="prototype"/>
    <bean id="com.ddklife.core.autovending.domain.OrderChannelXref" class="com.ddklife.core.autovending.domain.OrderChannelXrefImpl" scope="prototype"/>
    <bean id="org.broadleafcommerce.profile.core.domain.Customer" class="com.ddklife.core.customer.domain.CustomerImpl" scope="prototype"/>
</beans>
```

And here is my extended CustomerImpl class, I omitted all getters/setters methods:

```
package com.ddklife.core.customer.domain;

@Entity(name = "DdlCustomer")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "DDL_CUSTOMER")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="DD_READ_CUSTOMER_BY_WECHATOPENID", query="from DdlCustomer c where weChatOpenId = :weChatOpenId")
})
public class CustomerImpl extends org.broadleafcommerce.profile.core.domain.CustomerImpl implements Customer {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "DDLIFE_POINTS")
    protected Long ddlifePoints;

    @Column(name = "WECHAT_OPEN_ID")
    protected String weChatOpenId;

}
```

And here is my extended OrderImpl class, which could been loaded correctly from relative entities or using the `getBean` method of Spring context:

```
package com.ddklife.core.ecommerce.domain;

@Entity(name = "DdlOrder")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "DDL_ORDER")
public class OrderImpl extends org.broadleafcommerce.core.order.domain.OrderImpl implements Order {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "STORE_TYPE")
    protected String storeType;

    @Column(name = "STORE_ID")
    protected Long storeId;

    @Column(name = "PAYMENT_QRCODE_URL")
    protected String paymentQrcodeUrl;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = OrderChannelXrefImpl.class, mappedBy = "order", orphanRemoval = true,
            cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    protected List<OrderChannelXref> allChannelXrefs = new ArrayList<OrderChannelXref>();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the entirety of your applicationContext-entity.xml? It should look like this:

```
<bean id="org.broadleafcommerce.profile.core.domain.Customer" class="com.mycompany.core.MyCustomer" scope="prototype" />
```

Things that could be going on:

1. You've got active sessions that already had a Broadleaf CustomerImpl stored there prior to your override; try clearing out all your cookies and trying again
2. You didn't do a mvn install of the core project prior to rebuilding the 'site' war file. When you go to build the site project, you need to make sure the core project is also included. You can do this with this Maven command from the root:

   mvn -pl site -am clean install

That will ensure that the 'site' module and its dependencies (like core) are rebuilt

Comment: Hi phillipuniverse, I have posted my applicationContext-entity.xml and the extended CustomerImpl class in my original question. I am wondering why I could extend OrderImpl successfully in the same way but failed in CustomerImpl. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint in CustomerDaoImpl.create() and see what happens when you go to the site in incognito mode, or after having cleared your cookies? You should see a new customer being created there. Is it still a Broadleaf CustomerImpl or your version of CustomerImpl?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your new entity to :
/core/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence-core.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="blPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    ...
    <class>com.mycompany.order.domain.MyOrderImpl</class>
    ...
</persistence-unit>
```